# how to populate column from the content of other columns after a row is inserted in the same table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table `traffic` with 7 columns, namely `toll_id`, `date1`, `shift`, `car_single`, `car_return`, `car_local` and `car_total`.

How could I populate first 5 columns manually, and then store a value in column `car_total`, which will be the sum of `car_single` and `car_return`?

Here is the image of my table:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to add a 3rd and 4th ways of achieving the desired outcome:

3. If you have at least MySQL v5.7.6, you can use a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) as `car_total`.
4. Alternatively, you can choose not to store `car_total` at all, but calculate this value on the fly while querying the table.

Having a column to store the results of the calculation is good if you regularly have search based on that field because you can use indexes to speed up the searches. Calculating the results on the fly may be better, if you just need to display the result of the calculation, but there is no need to filter on it.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do this:

- Add the logic in the application itself, so that it calculates total before inserting the record. (Recommended)
- Write an after insert trigger (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/trigger-syntax.html) which calculates the count when record is inserted.